# Nginx location rewrite rules not working behind ELB

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have 2 ec2 instances behind an App Load Balancer which reroute the traffic to the desired instance according to the path:

- www.example.com/hello => instance 1
- www.example.com/goodbye => instance 2

#### Nginx servers configuration

```
# Hello server config
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root  /home/ubuntu/welcome;
    }

    location = /hello {
        root  /home/ubuntu/api;
    }
```

```
# Goodbye server config
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root  /home/ubuntu/welcome;
    }

    location = /goodbye {
        root  /home/ubuntu/api;
    }
```

I have created a simple index.html file in each server under the root folder as specified in the config files, so that the instance1 return "Hello" and instance2 return "Goodbye". However www.example.com/hello and www.example.com/goodbye always return 404 not found.
I did reload my Nginx service and even restarted.

P.S: For the sake of testing, I created another instance with Nginx not hidden behind an ELB and edited the config to look similar and it seems to work so I am not sure what did I do wrong with the ones behind the ELB.

Comment: You have not defined an index for either paths, nginx has no idea what file to return. `root` is a directory that contains the file, not the filename to serve.

Comment: Doesn't Nginx takes index.html by default ? as the / seems to work fine. Anyway, I have update the config and it is still the same.

Comment: is `/home/ubuntu/api` a file or directory? and if it's a directory, does nginx have sufficent permission to read the index file on disk?

Comment: With your config nginx would look for an index file in `/home/ubuntu/api/hello` and `/home/ubuntu/api/goodbye` directories. If you want it to search an index file in `/home/ubuntu/api` directory instead, use an [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directive.

Comment: hey @Medi, have you checked in error and access logs for any clues yet? i think "localhost" as `server_name` might be wrong there. If you're trying to access the site as "www.example.com/something" then `server_name` should be "www.example.com" (or regex matching anything). Can you check that too please?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this by moving the root outside of the location brackets and update the name of my folders to match the name of location and it works. so now it looks like this.

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root  /home/ubuntu/api;

        location / {        
        }

        location = /hello {
        }
}
```

Path to hello source code is /home/ubuntu/api/hello/

Path to goodbye source code => /home/ubuntu/api/goodbye/